# The React Native Android component - ReactHorizontalScrollView quoted DiscouragePrivateAPI lint errors？

Tags: android, react-native, lint

I've been watching the React on Native framework from the Android Native components - `ReactHorizontalScrollView`, Found a method of `getOverScrollerFromParent` use reflection to obtain mScroller, but through access private API in the form of access to, will be lint to check out mistakes - **DiscouragePrivateAPI**, this way is not safe? In case the private API changes in the future, mScroller returns a null value? Is there a better solution? Here it the code:

```java
 @Nullable
  private OverScroller getOverScrollerFromParent() {
    OverScroller scroller;

    if (!sTriedToGetScrollerField) {
      sTriedToGetScrollerField = true;
      try {
//Reflective access to mScroller, which is not part of the public SDK and therefore likely to change in future Android releases
        sScrollerField = 
HorizontalScrollView.class.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
        sScrollerField.setAccessible(true);
      } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        FLog.w(
            TAG,
            "Failed to get mScroller field for HorizontalScrollView! "
                + "This app will exhibit the bounce-back scrolling bug :(");
      }
    }
    ...

    return scroller;
  }
```